# Better word for "non-overlapping"?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

Geographical timezones cover the Earth in such a way that two timezones never overlap; hence, they are **non-overlapping**.  But is there a better (shorter, without negation) word for this?

> "Unfortunately he's travelling, possibly to a non-overlapping
>   timezone, so I'm not sure when he can take the call."

*Distinct* and *discrete* come to mind, but they miss the nuance of continuously covering a surface and would not work in the sentence above (although just plain old *different* would).

Comment: How about "disjoint"?

Comment: I would think "distinct" covers it pretty much perfectly.

Comment: Given that overlapping timezones would be somewhat less useful than chocolate teapots, I don't really see any reason to even *mention* the fact that they're "non-overlapping". Just as we don't normally refer to "non-melting teapots" - they're just *teapots*.

Comment: I travel to *different* timezones myself. The non-overlapping part is assumed. If you mean more than one apart, then *nonadjacent* works. *Disjoint* might also be used, but is too math oriented for casual English. People will not understand you.

Comment: You could try *contiguous* if you really want to make the point.

Comment: What is it, in your own words? There are supposedly 40 time zones in the world. He could be in any of them but one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The timezones *partition* the globe (planet). That means that they do **not overlap**, that they are **contiguous**, and that they **cover the entire** globe.

Comment: I came to this q&a while searching for synonym for "non-overlapping". The OP clearly did his/her homework and the "distinct" in the question helped me. Thanks. But then why the OP accepted this answer? None of the bold words in this answer can be used to replace "non-overlapping" in the timezone example in the question. :-/

Comment: @RayLuo OP here. I found plain old "different timezone" to be a good enough answer for my case, but I'm open to better answers.